# Deploy django1.8 in a production server Apache+ mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to do the deploy at my project with django1.8, using apache 2.x and mod_wsgi, the structure of my project is (pd: mi proyect is in /var/www)

```
projectdjango
  apps  -- (my django-apps)
      ....
  projectdjango 
      settings
         local.py
         staging.py
         url.py 
  static
  templates
      ....
  manage.py
  projectdjango.wsgi
```

the code I'm using for the httpd.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName projectdjango.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/projectdjango

<Directory /var/www/ >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess projectdjango.com processes=2 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup projectdjango.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/projectdjango/projectdjango.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

and the code for projectdjango.wsgi is

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www')
sys.path.append('/var/www/projectdjango')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'projectdjango.settings.staging'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

error.log

```
[Thu Apr 23 16:44:48.540206 2015] [core:notice] [pid 21662:tid 140482308327296] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 23 16:45:43.715053 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 21662:tid 140482308327296] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 23 16:45:44.907958 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 21779:tid 140246657443712] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming n$
[Thu Apr 23 16:45:44.908339 2015] [core:notice] [pid 21779:tid 140246657443712] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 23 16:48:31.071450 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 21779:tid 140246657443712] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 23 16:48:32.282889 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 21909:tid 140394885306240] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming n$
[Thu Apr 23 16:48:32.283273 2015] [core:notice] [pid 21909:tid 140394885306240] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.620133 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.842564 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955] mod_wsgi (pid=21911): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.842699 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.842771 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handler$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.844350 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.844455 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handler$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.844851 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, s$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.844904 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handler$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.844979 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.845023 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.846871 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.846981 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.847070 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return t.render(c)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.847112 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/bas$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.848209 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return self._render(context)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.848293 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/bas$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.848394 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return self.nodelist.render(context)

[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.850682 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encodi$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851014 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     s = six.text_type(s)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851063 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functi$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851538 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851600 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851879 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.851963 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.852729 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.852805 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.852891 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.852933 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.852997 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.853037 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.853102 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     self._add_installed_apps_translations()
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.853143 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/transl$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.853208 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid 140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955]     "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before t$
[Thu Apr 23 21:49:47.853392 2015] [:error] [pid 21911:tid   140394723014400] [remote 127.0.0.1:16955] AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be init$
```

I hope someone can help me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you post the error and access logs?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: No, i'm using directly python3.4 in server, i use virtualenv in my pc,